# AWS Application Load Balancer forwarding to dynamic internal IP

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-vpc, aws-application-load-balancer

I have an AWS VPC subnet in which dynamically hosts are created and destroyed. My frontend will have to connect to them. My plan was to reverse proxy to them.

1. Backend creates an ec2 instance in said subnet
2. Backend reads its internal ip address
3. I send the internal IP address to the frontend
4. Frontend connects to DNS_NAME of load balancer of this network like this: my_public_dns_name.com/internal_ip

I wanted this load balancer to terminate TLS and forward to the request to the IP address in the path of the request. The subnet has a CIDR of 16, so it is a little impracticable to add 65k addresses manually for forwarding.

I couldn't figure out how to configure AWS application load balancer to do this. Is that even possible with it or do I have to use my own reverse proxy on an instance?

Comment: Unusual requirement, can you explain why you want to do this? Perhaps look at ALB with dynamic path routing, one target group per back-end EC2 host. You'd have to dynamically update the ALB's [path-based routing](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/elb-achieve-path-based-routing-alb/) config as hosts come and go. Or even replace ALB with API Gateway HTTP APIs and use its [path-based routing](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/http-api-develop-routes.html) similarly.

Comment: That's unfortunate if I have to update those dynamically. This will add complexity. Why I need it is because my website allows my customer to start and connect to virtual machines dynamically. The connection happens via NoVNC, which uses web sockets and those need ssl termination.

Comment: The EC2 instances don't have public IPs, presumably, otherwise the client could be load-balanced to one of them arbitrarily and then the back-end could advertise its public IP for the client to connect to over WebSocket. Also note that APIG support WebSockets and you can configure [API integration](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/apigateway-websocket-api-integration-requests.html). I suspect this would take some dynamic configuration regardless (if it worked at all).

Comment: It does work with public IP addresses. We have that already running. The issue is that WebSockets from https websites are forbidden (browser-side) to connect to non-secure endpoints. This would require us to either create a certificate for every customer instance or use a wild card. Impractically, due to customers using those machines and the private keys shouldn't be on it. Therefore I wanted to terminate it in a step before that. And that's why we want to take their public IPs away.

Comment: Interesting problem. Wonder if you could do this via multiple ALB listeners with unique ports, one per back-end host. So, instead of path-based routing, the client is made aware of a specific port on the ALB that leads to a specific back-end. Again, probably dynamic config as hosts come and go. See [here](https://techholding.co/blog/aws-websocket-alb-ecs/) which might prompt some ideas (ECS service can automatically register itself with the load balancer, for example).

Comment: I think you're right. There is no way around configuring it when the hosts comes up. Guess it's time for the backend to learn new skills :). Thank you